# Right border not showing in bootstrap + glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a problem with the following code :

```
        <div class="row" id="thierry_poirier" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-md-1" align="center">
            <img src='images/profil_80.jpg' class="img-responsive img-rounded" align="center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <b>Thierry Poirier</b></span></span><br>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">  thierry.poirier@earthcase.eu</span></span><br>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">  06.26.51.55.75</span></span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
                <li>Associé Gérant, expert sûreté sécurité</li>
                <li>Ancien officier marinier du bataillon des marins pompiers de Marseille, directeur d'exploitations portuaires, responsable sécurité sûreté de ports de plaisance et de commerce</li>
                <li>En charge des volets sûreté-sécurité-accessibilité, exploitation et formations</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first glyphicon's right border doesn't end like the others do.

Anyone has any idea why ?

If you want to see the problem you can also go on this website (hosting the current version of the website) :

http://digitera.ddns.net/aboutUs.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem. :)

bootstrap.min.css

```
.input-group-addon:first-child {
border-right: 0;
```

}

Remove or override this line in your custom css and it should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !